# configuring castle monorail to not show any extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, castle-monorail

how can I configure Castle Monorail to not have any extensions? I looked at the documentation and have confugred it's defaultUrlExtension to blank and have also configured it to not use extensions but I'm still getting .castle extension on the urls. What am I missing ? thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of IIS are you using?

Comment: IIS 6 and Visual Stuadio's built in server when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MonoRail_Configure(IMonoRailConfiguration configuration)
{
  configuration.UrlConfig.UseExtensions = false;
}
```